# How to strike through a list item without disturbing other items in a html list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Through this code, on clicking on any one list item, all the other list items get struck through, what should be changed here, so that, only that list item is struck which is clicked on?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    function struck(ele) {
      ele.style = "text-decoration:line-through; list-style-type:none";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>A list</h2>

  <ul id="demo" style="list-style-type:none;" onclick="struck(this)">
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function struck(ele){
    ele.style="text-decoration:line-through;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>A list</h2>

<ul id = "demo" style="list-style-type:none;">
 <li onclick="struck(this)">Coffee</li>
 <li onclick="struck(this)">Tea</li>
 <li onclick="struck(this)">Milk</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u suggest a way to apply this property in an empty list, in which items will be appended later on

Answer (score 0):

the `onclick` event must be on the li elements instead
here's the code sample https://jsfiddle.net/k1Lywnz6/

Comment: Can u suggest a way to apply this property in an empty list, in which items will be appended later on

Answer (score 0):

This working example may help you to solve this problem   [link](http://jsfiddle.net/dtzjN/)

```js
var classHighlight = 'highlight';
var $thumbs = $('.thumbnail').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $thumbs.removeClass(classHighlight);
    $(this).addClass(classHighlight);
});
```

```css
.highlight {
    background-color: cyan;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change onclick on ul to li element.

```
<ul id = "demo" style="list-style-type:none;">
    <li onclick="struck(this)">Coffee</li>
    <li onclick="struck(this)">Tea</li>
    <li onclick="struck(this)">Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `li` elements and add your style change code in to `onclick` event as per below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.onload = () => {
    let ls = document.querySelectorAll('#demo li');
    ls.forEach((ele) => {
       ele.onclick = (ele) => {
          ele.target.style="text-decoration:line-through; list-style-type:none";
       };
    });

}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>A list</h2>

<ul id = "demo" style="list-style-type:none;">
 <li>Coffee</li>
 <li>Tea</li>
 <li>Milk</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can u suggest a way to apply this property in an empty list, in which items will be appended later on

Comment: When the empty list is going to be appended. Are you going to do with another js function?

Comment: yes, `var entry = document.createElement('li');   entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data));  list.appendChild(entry);` here, entry is my list item and I am appending it to list

Comment: then you can add `onclick` event while you are appending them to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another simple solution :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function struck(id){
var v = parseInt(id);
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");


if(document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration=='line-through')       
{ 
document.getElementById(id).style.textDecoration='none';
} 


for (i = v+1; i <= list.length ; i++) { 

document.getElementById(i).style.textDecoration='line-through';
document.getElementById(i).style.listStyle='none';
}

for (i = v-1; i >=0 ; i--) { 

 document.getElementById(i).style.textDecoration='line-through';
document.getElementById(i).style.listStyle='none';
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2 id = "head">A list</h2>

<ul id = "demo" style="list-style-type:none;" >
<li id="1" onclick="struck('1')">Coffee</li>
<li id ="2" onclick="struck('2')">Tea</li>
<li id ="3" onclick="struck('3')">Milk</li>
</ul>  

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the first answer and it works like a charm.But the issue I was having was once I have struck through an item on the list my accident I could not undo it so I edited the code a little bit to undo the change

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<style>
.cancelled{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    opacity: .5;
}
</style>
    <script>
    window.onload = () => {
        let ls = document.querySelectorAll('#demo li');
        ls.forEach((ele) => {
           ele.onclick = (ele) => {
              $(ele.target).toggleClass("cancelled");
           };
        });
    
    }
    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <h2>A list</h2>
    
    <ul id = "demo" >
     <li>Coffee</li>
     <li>Tea</li>
     <li>Milk</li>
    </ul>  
    
    </body>
    </html>
```